# Ideals in projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

If our field $K$ is not algebraically closed, and if we have $I$ a homogeneous ideal in the polynomial ring $K[x]$ and $V$ is a projective variety, then can we say $I(V(I))=\sqrt I$ ?

Comment: V(I) may well be empty.

Comment: OK, Did you mean that I(V(I))=√I  wrong if the  field K is not algebraically closed. ?
and if we assume that V(I) is not empty?